# Trying to remove first few characters from each line but not able to remove ./

Tags: shell-script, shell

Consider this as file :

```
M  ../.gitlab-ci.yml
M  ../force-app/main/ui/classes/test.cls
A  ../pmd/get_diff_branches.sh
?? ../assets/server.key
?? ./
```

I am removing all the extra character from line one by one like this :

```
sed /^D/d diff.txt | sed 's/^..//' | sed /^force-app/p | sed /^force-app\\/package\.xml/d | sed 's/.*\ ->\ //' > temp.txt
```

After doing so the file looks like this:

```
 ../.gitlab-ci.yml
 ../assets/server.key
 ../force-app/main/ui/classes/test.cls
 ../pmd/get_diff_branches.sh
 ./
```

How do I remove `./` too in the same line, if I write another command then it will start removing `./` from all lines, but I only want `./` to be removed when there is an exact match, like the last line in the above snippet.

Operating System : **Linux 10**

Comment: Try this: `s#^\./$##`

Comment: No doesn't work

Comment: What operating system are you using? Sed implementation vary significantly between systems. Please [edit] your question and add your operating system.

Comment: Updated OS details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no need for separate `sed` commands. You can string multiple commands together with `-e` or, if your `sed` supports it, just separate them with `;`. Also, one of your commands will just duplicate a line: `sed /^force-app/p`. That only makes sense, assuming you don't want to duplicate the line, if you use `sed -n` to suppress printing.

This should do what you want if you have GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^[^ ]*  *//; /\/force-app\/package\.xml/d; /^\.\/$/d' file
../.gitlab-ci.yml
../force-app/main/ui/classes/test.cls
../pmd/get_diff_branches.sh
../assets/server.key
```

And, if you don't have GNU `sed`, try:

```
$ sed -e 's/^[^ ]*  *//' -e '/\/force-app\/package\.xml/d' -e '/^\.\/$/d' file
../.gitlab-ci.yml
../force-app/main/ui/classes/test.cls
../pmd/get_diff_branches.sh
../assets/server.key
```

The commands are:

- `s/^[^ ]*  *//`: remove all non-space characters followed by 0 or more spaces from the beginning of the line.
- `/\/force-app\/package\.xml/d`: if this line matches `/force-app/package.xml`, delete it. I am guessing here, since your example didn't include any lines matching this pattern. You were using `^force-app...`, but that can't be right since you would always have a `/` before it.
- `/^\.\/$/d`: remove any lines that consist of *only* `./` and nothing else.